# JButton vertical text alignment

Tags: java, html, swing, jbutton, vertical-alignment

Hi I am making a project for college for a gallery, I have the receipt in a JList and want to put some buttons at the side of it but I am picky and want the text on the JButtons to be vertical. At the moment I am using html and putting a `<br>` in between the letters, this is giving me a really large gap between the letters. Is there a better way of doing this which is reasonably easy. Thanks

Comment: it might get crazy but have you tried using `<Table><tr><td>...</tr></Table>` ?

Comment: thanks good idea but it still leaves a huge gap

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to extend [BasicButtonUI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicButtonUI.html) to display the text vertically.  [This tutorial](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/11/15/rotate-jbutton-to-vertical/) provides sample code overriding `BasicButtonUI` to simply rotate text either 90 or 270 degrees (text looks like it has been rotated as opposed to reading top to bottom with each character facing the normal way as in a `<br />`-separated button).  To actually paint the text as in

> B
>
> u
>
> t
>
> t
>
> o
>
> n

you will need to modify the sample code.  The pattern provided is a good place to start.

Comment: this is exactly what is needed - good pointer(+1). However, rotation would not satisfy "picky" @Site T it seems. Rotation would rotate the whole text to a vertical axis. Basically he/she would have to extend BasicButtonUI and then in paint method, paint the text in such a way that the text is broken down to individual letters and painted one by one followed by a virtual line break derived using font metrics of current font in use.

Comment: Link of this tutorial is broken. I found [that link on web.archieve.](https://web.archive.org/web/20190507195837/http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/11/15/rotate-jbutton-to-vertical/)